# ACRA cound not handle exception happens within Application#onCreate()

Tags: android, acra

I'm using [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra) in my android application.

But I find that when exception happens within Application#onCreate() method,it only save the report file,rather than raising the dialog to send it.

It there something wrong with my code?

```
@ReportsCrashes(formKey="")
public class MyAndroidApplication extends Application
{
        public void onCreate()
        {
            ACRAConfiguration config = ACRA.getConfig();
            config.setMailTo("test@test.com");
            config.setResToastText(R.string.acra_toast);
            config.setResDialogText(R.string.acra_dlg_txt);
            config.setResDialogCommentPrompt(R.string.acra_dlg_comment_prpmpt);
            try
            {
                config.setMode(ReportingInteractionMode.DIALOG);
            }
            catch (ACRAConfigurationException e)
            {
                logger.error("fail to config ACRA", e);
                return;
            }
            ACRA.setConfig(config);
            ACRA.init(this);
            someMethodThrowsException();
        }
}
```

Comment: instead of logger.error, try e.printStackTrace()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onCreate` of the `Application` is called before any `Activity` is created and does not have a UI, therefore ACRA cannot display a dialog.  From the [android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onCreate%28%29) for `onCreate`

> Called when the application is starting, before any activity, service,
>   or receiver objects (excluding content providers) have been created.
>   Implementations should be as quick as possible (for example using lazy
>   initialization of state) since the time spent in this function
>   directly impacts the performance of starting the first activity,
>   service, or receiver in a process. If you override this method, be
>   sure to call super.onCreate().

So, be sure to call `super.onCreate()`, which your example above is missing, and you should not be doing a whole lot in there that would cause exceptions.

Comment: So if exception happens in Application#oncreate,we should not use Dialog mode?

Comment: You can still use it, it just won't show the dialog, and therefore probably won't email the error report to you (because dialog confirms the report with the user).  I personally use a `Toast` with automatic submission, and then provide a "Automatically Send Crash Reports" option in my preferences.

Comment: It seems I'd better change to toast mode.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing two problems with your code.

1. You don't call `super.onCreate()` after initializing ACRA
2. Your class should have tha annotation `@Reportscrashes` even if the parameters are set at runtime. Otherwise you will get an error in logcat saying *ACRA#init called but no ReportsCrashes annotation on Application*

Also, I'm not sure if the Application can show a dialog because it has no UI layout associated with it. Toast reporting works fine if you change both points above.

Comment: 1.I have checked the super class android.app.Application#onCreate(),and it does nothing.<br/>2.

Comment: 2.I have added the @ReportCrashes annotation but still no dialog.Maybe it's because what you said application has no UI layout..